# Excel: Add dynamically parent numbers

Tags: excel, tree, parent-child, nodes

I have a excel document with 10.000 taxonomywords. I need to add the parent ID for all the items.

Her is an example:

```
A  B         C      D        E  
ID ParentID   
1  0         Sport
2  1                Fotball
3  2                         bla1
4  1                Handball 
5  4                         bla34
```

How can I dynamically fillout the parent node ID number based on the depth of the tree in Excel 2013? (Up to 7 levels in this case)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution

```
=IF(C2<>"";0;IF(D2<>"";LOOKUP(A2;1/(C$2:C2<>"");A$2:A2);IF(E2<>"";LOOKUP(A2;1/(D$2:D2<>"");A$2:A2);IF(F2<>"";LOOKUP(A2;1/(E$2:E2<>"");A$2:A2);IF(G2<>"";LOOKUP(A2;1/(F$2:F2<>"");A$2:A2);IF(H2<>"";LOOKUP(A2;1/(G$2:G2<>"");A$2:A2)))))))
```

Used on column B.